# Any way to make it assume transient unless explictly told otherwise?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

It does not look like there is from the research I've done but is there any way in which it is possible to make Hibernate assume a field/property is not intended for ORM unless explictly adding `@Column`?

I know about `@Transient`. Adding it hundreds of times for the few fields that are being persisted is what is trying to be avoided.

Comment: If the majority of your fields *do not* get mapped, then you need to revisit your design. Perhaps you should extract those fields that *do* get mapped into new classes, and let your old classes hold instances of them.

Comment: I'd love to but this is dealing with design decisions already taken. I'm trying to avoid a massive refactoring exercise if possible.

Answer (score -1):

With JPA, as soon as a class is annotated with @Entity, all its attributes are automatically mapped to a table. If you do not need to map an attribute, you can use the @javax.persistence.Transient annotation or the java transient keyword. So this is the default behavior of hibernate as JSR states.